# C++ Factories -> Java Factories?

Tags: java, c++, factory-pattern

When I was first learning C++, I came across this article about factories,
[Pluggable C++ Factory](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/reference/programming/multiplayer-and-networking/268/why-pluggable-factories-rock-my-multiplayer-world-r841), and ever since I've used that pattern for my factories in C++.  Now, I've been doing Java recently and on more than one occasion I've wanted to use a factory, but I can't seem to figure out a way to extend the factory at compile time.

Any implementation of a factory I can think of in Java involves telling the actual factory class about all of the underlying classes, which is rather suboptimal.

So, how can I get all subclasses of a class to register themselves in a static dictionary at compile time/program instantiation?

**EDIT** 
It seems that my question was too vague.  Let me elaborate,

In Java if I were to try to replicate this pattern like so:
Factory.java

```
abstract class Factory { 
private static Dictionary<int, Factory> dict;
public Factory(int index) {
  dict[int] = self;
}
public Foo getFoo(int index) {return dict[index].createFoo();}
protected abstract Foo makeFoo();
}
```

Derived.java

```
class Derived extends Factory {
public Derived() {super(DERIVED_INDEX);}
private static Derived tmp = new Derived();
public Foo makeFoo() {return new FooImplementation();}
}
```

The factory won't update with the reference to Derived (and thus won't create Derived instances) unless I manually register it myself, which defeats the purpose of having the static tmp member.

Comment: Don't think this warrants a `c++` tag

Comment: Given that everything in the referenced article is trivially transliterated to Java, what *exactly*, is the question?

Answer (score 0):

I think the [ServiceLoader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) class can help you here.

Answer (score 0):

Think of implementing Factory Method using Reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the [Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library useful.

> Using Reflections you can query your metadata such as:

```
* get all subtypes of some type
* get all types/methods/fields annotated with some annotation, w/o annotation parameters matching
* get all resources matching matching a regular expression
```

Using this library you can define an interface and a factory which can create any implementation of that interface (by searching for those implementations)